# how to add button to every item in a list view

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a layout with a listView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/testMain"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/notesListView"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:divider="#FFF"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"         
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:overScrollFooter="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"         
         />              
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I use ListView_Adapter to add items to the list dynamically.
Is it possible to add a button to the right corner of every row of the list?

Comment: you should search for making custom list....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to go for custom listview.In custom ListView you have to add listitem dynamically from layout xml file.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/testMain"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/notesListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

         />              
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your listitem xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/title"
 android:textColor="#FFF"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/Btn01"
  android:textColor="#000"
  android:layout_weight="0.20"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Check this [Buttons on List View](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)